Problem with "index" parameter with gsynth package in R
I am using the gsynth function in R with data imported from an excel file. The code I used is the following. I created a new dataframe after pulling the data from the excel file
outGDP <- gsynth(realGDP ~ treatmentGroup + slopePercentage, data = df, index=c(municipalityID, time), force = "two-way", r = c(1,5), se=TRUE, inference = "nonparametric", nboots = 2500, parallel = FALSE)
I am getting the following error:
Error in gsynth.default(formula = NULL, data = data, Y = Yname, D = Dname,  :  "index" option misspecified. Try, for example, index = c("unit.id", "time").
All help is appreciated.
See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsynth/gsynth.pdf
Package is based on "Generalized Synthetic Control Method: Causal Inference with Interactive Fixed Effects Models" by Xu (2017).
outGDP <- gsynth(realGDP ~ treatmentGroup + slopePercentage, data = df, index=c(municipalityID, time), force = "two-way", r = c(1,5), se=TRUE, inference = "nonparametric", nboots = 2500, parallel = FALSE)

Hi Dwaipayan, it is hard to help without a reproducible example. Looking at the documentation, i suspect that you may have forgotten to place quotations,", around the elements in the vector input for the index argument. The documentation states "index: a two-element string vector..." which is not the case in the provided code.
